# Fluid div with height dictated bybackground image

Tags: html, css

I have a background image in a div of 100% width. There is nothing else in the div. I want to be able to have the height of the div to always be the aspect ratio of the background image. Is there a way to do this?

So in other words when I scale down the page I want the div to scale down and maintain the same height of the background image.

I hope this makes sense,

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a combination of width, padding and background-size.

[Check out this](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/maintain-aspect-ratio-for-html-element-using-only-css-in-a-responsive-design/):

> The key lies in padding. Padding, whether being used to define top,
>   bottom, left, or right padding, is dependent upon the WIDTH of the
>   containing element when defined in percents. For example, if you say
>   “padding-top: 10%;” what you are actually saying is that the padding
>   on the top should be 10% of the WIDTH of the containing element. So
>   then, if you wish to make an element a responsive square, you simply
>   write this:

```
width: 20%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 20%;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I need but is is getting closer. I want the background image width to match the width of the div(which will always be 100%) while maintaining the same height of the aspect ratio. http://jsfiddle.net/sfKyk/1/ that image should be 100%.

Comment: I updated the fiddle there. Obviously it has to be set based on the aspect ratio of the image in question. Does this work for you? - http://jsfiddle.net/sfKyk/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you use img tag, you won't need to care about vertical resizing.

```
<div>
   <img src="..." style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: but he wants background image

Comment: Correct. A background image in a div with nothing else in the div.